# Ajax resposnse gives just OK text on perl website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, perl

I'm making some changes on my perl website (file manager)

I want to make pages to load faster and to have a nicer use of pages especially for files page hen content will be loaded with ajax everytime it's requested .

I have paging which works perfectly via ajax but when i want to do this after i click a button it doesnt work just gives me an OK text for response, below are codes I'm using  for paging

```
function setPagination(element, opts)
{
   $(element).paging(opts.total,
   {
      format: '< ncnn (- p) >',
      perpage: opts.perpage,
      onSelect: function (page)
      {
         if(document.readyState !== 'complete') return;
         $.ajax({
            url: opts.url,
            type: 'POST',
            data:
            {
               op: opts.op,
               load: opts.load,
               page: page.toString(),
               fld_id: opts.fld_id,
               usr_login: opts.usr_login
            },
            success: function(result)
            {
               $(opts.target).html(result);
               if(typeof addthis !== 'undefined') { addthis.layers.refresh(); }
            }
         });
      },
      onFormat: function (type)
      {
         var show_right = this.pages > 4;
         var show_block = !show_right || this.value != this.pages;
         if(this.pages <= 1) return '&nbsp;';
         /* TODO: looks ugly, needs refactoring */
         switch (type)
         {
            case 'right':
               if(!show_right) return '';
               return show_right
                  ? '<a>' + this.value + '</a>'
                  : '';
            case 'block':
               if(!show_block) return '';
               return this.value == this.page
                  ? '<span>' + this.value + '</span>'
                  : '<a>' + this.value + '</a>';
            case 'next': // >
               return '<a href="#" class="next">Next</a>';
            case 'prev': // <
               return '<a href="#" class="prev">Prev</a>'
            case 'fill':
               return show_right ? ".." : '';
         }
      }
   });
   $(element).css('cursor', 'pointer');
}
```

html code with perl

```
<div class="files"> 
   <div id="files_g">
       <TMPL_INCLUDE files_grid.html>
    </div>

     <div class="grid paging bottom"></div>
</div>


setPagination('.files .grid',
    {
        op: 'my_files', 
        total: '<TMPL_VAR files_total>',
        load: 'files_grid',
        target: '#files_g',
        perpage: '<TMPL_VAR per_page>',
        fld_id: '<TMPL_VAR folder_id>',
    });
```

That's the paging page which i use to  load the file content only not the entire page and it work perfectly .

Now I want to select a file and after clicking to set an custom options for the that file i have select after this i want the file content to reload here is where i cant find out why is'nt working

below are codes that i want to use

```
function setFileFlag(file_ids, name, value) {
                       $.ajax({
                           type: 'POST',
                           url: '?',
                           data: {
                               op: 'my_files',
                               set_flag: name,
                               load: 'files_grid',
                               value: value,
                               file_id: file_ids,
                           },
                           success: function(result) {
                               $('#files_g').html(result);
                               if(typeof addthis !== 'undefined') { addthis.layers.refresh(); }

                           },
                       });
                    }
                    $('.flag').click(function() {
                        var name = this.name.replace(/(un)?set_/,'');
                        var value = this.name.match(/^set_/) ? 1 : 0;
                        var file_ids = $('[name=F1] [name=file_id]')
                            .filter(function() { return this.value != 0 && this.checked; })
                            .map(function() { return(parseInt(this.value)) })
                            .toArray();
                        setFileFlag(file_ids, name, value);


                    });
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. Where do you get that OK?

Comment: I just give loads of code to have better understanding on it ,, the OK text i get after the ajax response ,, with paging i get the files  but with this no just OK text